# Product questions in Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

I need some guidance in how to go about this.

I have some products (ubercart using Drupal 7) for which the users need to answer some questions with yes and no, before buying the product.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Ubercart Webform Checkout Pane](http://drupal.org/project/uc_webform_pane) module.

> This module allows you to define Webform nodes as checkout/order panes
>   in Ubercart.
>
> This is useful if you want to collect additional information during
>   the checkout process. For example, you may want a quick survey or
>   require additional fields that apply to the entire order.